# Save JSON object after using callback function from POST HTTP request

Tags: node.js, http, callback, request

I want to be able to use "answer" as a variable inside any other function. How can I do that?

Code:

```
var answer = function name("happy", function(body){console.log(body) });
```

Comment: Full code:   function getJSON ( input, callback){
    var all = {
      'documents': [ ...]
       
    };
    request({
        headers: {
          'Host' : 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com'
        },
        uri: 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment',
          json: true,
    
        body: all,
        method: 'POST'
      }, function (error, response, body) {
    
             if (error) {
           callback(error || {statusCode: response.statusCode});
        }
        else
        callback(body);  
      });
    }

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit hard to understand what you want to achieve, but if I guessed correctly you're on a good way. I think you already can do it, you just don't in your code. Is this what you want?

```
function getJSON(input, callback) {
    var all = {'documents': [...]};
    request({
        headers: {'Host': 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com'},
        uri: 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/…',
        json: true, body: all, method: 'POST'
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {callback(error || {statusCode: response.statusCode});} else callback(body);
        });
}

function myOtherFunction(bodyOrError){
    console.log(bodyOrError);
};

getJSON('testInput', myOtherFunction);
```

And one more thing: you've posted code in very unreadable manner, please edit your initial question and post all the code there.